# Store this dataframe to Hbase

Tags: scala, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I Have this dataframe whose schema is:

```
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sentences: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- sentence: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- tokens: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ner: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- pos: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to save it in Hbase table with "id" and "sentence" as row key, and that hbase table has 2 column families, "ner" and "pos" with "tokens" as both of their keys. Doing it in scala

This is coming through spark streaming.

Comment: Please show us the code I.e. whatever you have tried till now?

Comment: I need to convert it to Put object to send to hbase, still looking if i can send dataframe in function or shall I convert it in Row RDD to pass through function. @notionquest

Comment: Have you been able to store this to hbase?

Comment: Yes, you can close it